# javadoc can't find package on command line

Tags: java, javadoc

I have this sample code and I'm trying to produce the javadoc for it. From the same directory where my package `test` is defined (see code below) I'm executing  `javadoc test` on the command line and I get:

```
Loading source files for package test...
javadoc: error - No source files for package test
1 error
```

The extent of the code is in Docs.java, shown here:

```
package test;

/**
 * this is some text
 */
class Docs {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("I'm in a package!");
    }
}
```

Here is the Java version info:

```
bash-3.2$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.8 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.8+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.8+10, mixed mode)
```

I haven't found a clear answer online why javadoc can't find the package. Any help appreciated!
(edited per requests)

Comment: Which java version do you use ? How do you setup javadoc  ? (Plugin with maven, gradle ...)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more detail, in particular the path to the source code from the directory you run the `javadoc` command, and all arguments you pass to `javadoc`.

Comment: @TraychoIvanov I don't know what setup javadoc would need before working. The tool seems to exist otherwise I wouldn't get the error message I get. As stated, I'm running in the command line, not in any gui utility

Comment: The problem might be in which directory your are executing the command. If using linux please post the result of "pwd" before executing the command or result of "cd" for windows.

Comment: @MauricioGuzinski I'm executing the javadoc command from the same directory in which the Docs.java file (and the compiled Docs.class file) exist.

Comment: @BBrooklyn, this is the problem, I think. You should execute outside the package. You must be at the same level of the "test" package directory. So "javadoc test" should work. If the "test" package is at /tmp/test, you should execute from /tmp

Comment: Awesome, that did it! Also it seems to be the case that the directory has to have the same name as the package

Comment: Yes, Java package structure is usually tied closely to directory structure; not just for Javadoc but also for compiling and running the code. You may want to check [the Java tutorial on packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be at the same level of the "test" package directory. So "javadoc test" should work. If the "test" package is at /tmp/test, you should execute from /tmp